# .htaccess rewrite leaves broken images

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have created a .htaccess file which cleans up my PHP query URLs.

Works well, but my images are broken and the index.php within the sub-cat folder

Any ideas how to fix these?

```
#Options +MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^(removephp-attheend)$ $1.php [NC,L]

ErrorDocument 404 /error-404.php
#error 404
RewriteRule    ^error/?$    error-404.php    [QSA,NC,L]

RewriteRule    ^category/sub-cat/([-0-9a-zA-Z]+) category/sub-cat/page.php?art_url=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```

Comment: In your pages inside `<head>...</head>`, use `<base href="/">`.

Comment: @JM-AGMS I should have mentioned I have even tried this. No cigar I'm afraid

Comment: Try opening one of the broken images in a new tab. You can see the URL that it's using. You can adjust your relative urls on your images or base href until the image starts working.

Comment: @JM-AGMS yeah I've tried this in dev tools also. nothing's working. the index.php in sub-cat/ also isn't working so I'm thinking it's something to do with the .htaccess file itself that I am not doing right or missing.